# How to dump a Windows XP image onto a brand new and no partition hard disk drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, bsod

I am trying to replicate a BSoD.

1. I want to be able to restore a Windows XP imaged file onto a fresh hard disk drive without partitioning or initializing it.

or

2. Is there a way that I can blank the MBR?

I do not want to clean or repair the MBR, i just want to blank or clear it from existent if possible.

Comment: What kind of image/how was it made?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong Linux background so i'll answer in linux-way.
you may boot your system with a linux rescue livecd and perform my suggestions.
the answer assume certain unix knowledge, but just comment and i'll clarify.

1. you may simply use the 'dd' tool to make copy of your windows XP installation at block level

for example:

```
    dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb   # backup the entire disk, given /dev/sda being the xp install, 
                                   and /dev/sdb being the fresh hard drive.
```

or copy only the concerning partition  if=/dev/sda1

*note if you replace of= with a file name instead of hard drive path, it would write disk image into file.

2. to erase the MBR, you may use dd also

   ```
   $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1  # delete the entire MBR (including bootloader and partition table)
   $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1  # delete only the bootloader
   ```

Comment: Your *"delete only the bootloader"* won't work. A complete sector has to be written at a time.  You cannot write just a partial sector, and expect the rest of the sector to remain intact.  A block device such as a disk drive simply does not work that way.  See http://superuser.com/questions/427554/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-previous-byte-position-on-a-hard-drive-after-it-has/427611#427611

Answer (score 0):

1. To answer your first question, any imaging software that's made nowadays allows you to image a logical partition or an entire hard drive (raw, forensic, call it what you will).  I personally like O&O Diskimage.  From there, you boot from your imaging software's ISO/USB stick and restore the image, the MBR will be transferred.
2. MBRWizard 3.0.73 Directly update and modify the Master Boot Record.
   MbrFix 1.3 Backup, restore and fix the boot code in the MBR.
   MBR Utility 1.05 Manipulate a drive's master boot record (MBR) via the command line.
   MBRWork 1.08 A utility to perform some common and uncommon MBR functions.
   MBRTool 2.3.200 Backup, verify, restore, edit, refresh, remove, display, re-write and more.
   MBR SAVE / RESTORE 2.1 BootSave and BootRest tools to save / restore MBR.
   BootICE 2012.09.20 A boot sector manipulation utility to edit MBR/PBR/BCD.

Enough? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem that was causing the BSOD (7B) issue.  Physical disk drive fault, it turns out the SSD power connector PIN 1 was slightly broken therefore it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work.  If i had less coffee on that day i would have noticed it.

Thank you all for all the suggestions, really appreciated!